# Unable to create an empty activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm unable to create an empty activity for the Miwok app. The options are inactive. I'm a complete beginner

[image: The problem]

Comment: what's your `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: Where will I find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your Minsdkversion. for this follow the below:

1.First, from the Project section that is available on the left side of the android studio, click on Gradle Scripts.

2. Second, Open build.gradle file that is related to the app module.
3. at default configs section you can find Minsdkversion, change it to an SDK after 17 or more, and after that sync project.

Comment: why does the sdk version make a difference here ? also, if OP is really new to programming, it might be easier to just suggest making a new project and increasing the sdk version from there

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes you are right, but I think It's not bad for him to know this way too because he is a beginner and he should know how he can change the Minksdkversion, always you can't say, ok no problem, try to make a new project.

Comment: Thank you and Sorry! Where do I find the default configuration section in the build.gradle file?

Comment: but why does the minSdk version cause this issue ?

Comment: because android is developed year by year and in each version, we have new features that are not compatible with all devices because their Hardware resources are not enough, So, developing apps for those devices are not beneficial And Android studio don't support these devices.

Answer (score 0):

From build.gadle:app add minSdkVersion 17

minSdkVersion 11 (build.Gradle:app)

[image]

minSdkVersion 17 (build.Gradle:app)

[image]